# android studio Error:Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, android, jvm, user-guide, gradle-daemon

Version of Android Studio 2.2
OS version: Windows 10
Java JRE/JDK version: 1.8.0_51

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be
>    caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
>    unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>    chapter on the daemon at
>    https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please
>    read the following process output to find out more:
>    ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Answer (score 11):

Im using Android studio version 2.2.2 on win 10 (32 bit) and this is how i fix this issue:

1. Open your newly created project.
2. Now open gradle.properties and change the JVM argument.
   i.e org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m 
   Basically it comes with default value of -Xm1536m which somehow is not working (at least for me).
3. Then Rebuild the project and it should work.

Answer (score 9):

add this line instead of following line in gradle.properties file

comment this line `#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`

add this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: works for: Android Studio 3.0.1, JRE: 1.8.0_152, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your **.gradle** from `C:\Users\<username>` directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In your project file\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js
Search for args.push and search for the line with the below description.
Mine was Xmx2048m. I changed to Xmx1024m and it worked. 16MB of RAM in my pc. Change

```
args.push('-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m');
```