# Android Studio Error: Unable to start daemon process

Tags: sdk

The android studio was working completely fine for 4 weeks, But from today I had got the error as bellow when i opened the android studio.
I had tried all the below-mentioned link but it doesn't work in my case so somebody help me

1.[Android Studio create new project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646184/android-studio-create-new-project-error)

2.[android studio Error:Unable to start the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910770/android-studio-errorunable-to-start-the-daemon-process)

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Comment: take a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/25009717/2756125

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated anything,
go to gradle directory in your computer ex: C:\Users\<>.gradle
 .if you have a gradle.properties file in this folder,open with notepad and add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

if you have 4gb RAM use above line or else if you have 8 or 16 gigs you can use 1024m instead of 512m
if you don't have gradle.properties file then create a new file and enter

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```