# Unable to create build ionic3 using command ionic build android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I set an environment path for `JAVA_HOME` and followed
[android studio Error:Unable to start the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910770/android-studio-errorunable-to-start-the-daemon-process).

I'm still getting an error, not able to create build. I am using latest version of node, npm, ionic.

Error:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
[12:02:18]  lint finished in 9.73 s
[Fatal Error] gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed
log.

[Fatal Error] android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.5.pom:2:1: Content is not all
 prolog.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your cordova? After updating it might be run. Or you can remove `nodemodule` folder and then do `npm install` and then try to build your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I am using updated version of cordova, node, npm and ionic. And also reinstall npm and platform, but didn't work for me.

Comment: @PoojaPradhan, Issue is already here (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3056) I solved this by removing all platforms (android and ios) and then again add it. and build the project